# Why is a featured post suddenly listed in the FAQ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sidebar

My understanding is that the "Frequently asked" section displays the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions, possibly in order of views. The "question-ban" one is *always* on top, but today the moderator welcome message is!

Now, I want to welcome our new moderators as much as everyone else, but is this supposed to be there? I visited the post to check and it isn't even tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

You can see this list on the homepage: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

[image]

Comment: What page are you seeing this behavior on? Maybe include a link?

Comment: @bluefeet That list appears on the homepage: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it's actually the FAQ *and Featured* sidebar. A holdover from the days when Meta didn't have a bulletin.

It remains a good reminder to un-feature things once they've gotten a bit of exposure...

Comment: Huh, I don't remember *other* featured posts doing that, I'll have to check the next time one comes around!

Comment: Shows how well that worked, eh? Hence the current bulletin-style display on every page.

Comment: I would think the big bulletin is a better reminder.

Comment: You'd think... But folks complain more when we leave the obscure one cluttered.