# Remove [featured] from retiring new nav

Tags: discussion, featured-questions

[Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0?cb=1) has been [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) for a long time now and has resulted in the bug where it appears in the FAQ.

Is it time to make this post no longer featured?

Comment: [meta-tag:featured] posts always appear in the [meta-tag:faq], it isn't a bug.

Comment: @BhargavRao ["holdover"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297183/1398425) to me this means its a bug that isn't being addressed.

Comment: The post is being featured to let people that relied on it know why it is gone. We had a *lot* of questions here on Meta about the issue until the post was featured. I don't think it is time to retire it just yet.

Comment: The Community user will remove the tag 30 days after it was added.

Comment: @gparyani citation please

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281797/when-and-why-is-the-featured-tag-removed-by-the-community-user

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag won't last very long (30~40 days) before [it'll automatically disppear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281797/350567), like the one on [my post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2321/4) did.

You can safely assume it'll go on its own before 2018 (it was added on Nov 21).